# Issue with PHP login & registration form without using a database

Tags: php

Could anyone help me making a login function that checks the txt document if user and pw exists/are correct? -and if they are, sends you to a logged in page. This is for a assignment which is why I have to store the information in a text document, I know it's unsafe. Also i know i should use $_Sessions but I'm not sure how to use it  and where to put it.

So far I have created the form which has 2 buttons one for registering and

Comment: Please don't just ask the community to solve a task for you. You are expected to make an effort and ask questions about specific problems you run into.

Comment: if only youve seen my youtube and search history for the past 2 days

Comment: Regardless, you've simply presented a blank login function, expecting someone else to create the full functionality. If you've made actual attempts at implementing it, please share them and describe at which step you've encountered a problem.

Comment: updated what i have tried but i am very lost as to why its not even working. I am very new to this :(

Comment: Good, we're making progress. Can you please add the information about the structure of the file where you keep your users?

Comment: once you register the information will get saved into the txt file like this: 

username: $2y$10$CNLMBL8dDkSnVDcO5tRh/OBc/XpDO3pjLN56CBaz9Fvg4S.wVqpdu
randomuser: $2y$10$wiTkAVOV4KBZJ5yJVFrELeI9MFZVVKUmXL0Z7KOgVD8g6LBPga.uC

Comment: If you take a closer look, you're not using the password the user supplied (variable `$pass` isn't used anywhere inside the login function), you're giving the hash function an empty string in the place of the password: `if (trim($tmp[1]) == trim(password_hash('', PASSWORD_DEFAULT))){`.

Comment: would it be something like this `if (trim($tmp[1]) == trim($hash)){`

Answer (score 1):

in your `register` method you are not passing password ?

```
$hash = password_hash('', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

also in your `login` method you need `password_verify` instead of `password_hash`

```
if (password_verify(trim($pass), trim($tmp[1]))){
```

Comment: the information is being saved in the textfile  so I assumed the password was being passed.I changed the line in the login but i dont know if it made a difference